# Download files from folder with webmatrix

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I have a folder created to get the files that users upload. However when i try to download the files, some extensions don't download.

I have this code to list all files that are in the folder, i can see all the files with no problem.

```
@foreach (string fullFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedFiles"),"Ticket Id - "+@id)))
                {
                    <div class="linkFicheiros"><a href="@Href("~/uploadedFiles","Ticket Id - "+@id, Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath))">@Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath)</a></div>
                }
```

With this line

```
<a href="@Href("~/uploadedFiles","Ticket Id - "+@id, Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath))">@Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath)</a>
```

i can download files with extension: ".zip" , ".xls" but extensions like ".msg"(sometimes users need to upload this extension) i got an error "The page cannot be found". Even ".jpg" instead of downloading the file it opens the image on the browser.

I think that is something how i'm trying to reach the file, but i can't get to a solution.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser would try to always view the content of the file. If its an Image file like **.jng** etc. But if there is a **.zip** file, it would let the user download and open it. Because browser can't open it.

You need to push the file to the user. For that you can try the following code:

```
var file = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + Request["img"]);
Response.AppendHeader(
"content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
Request["img"]);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.TransmitFile(file);
```

Now, you can see that in the code I am sharing, the file is a variable, which is being pointed to the file in the File System. Please note that there is a Query String parameter, which would be sent alongwith the URL, for example:

Download Image

Now the header would be appened, and the

```
Request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
```

is used to force the browser to show the Dialoug of Open/Save.

Then the transmit file to download it.

#### To only execute the code when needed

To only execute that download code block, you need to set the value in a block for condition to be true. For example, you can use a parameter to check whether to download the file or not. Try something simple like,

```
<a href="~/download_file/image_link.png?download=true>Download</a>
```

Then on the code behind use this:

```
var download = Request.QueryString["download"];
if(download == "true") {
  /* place the code here */
}
```

Now it would only execute if the condition is true, otherwise it would skip that part.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just one thing. How can i assign that to each file. Like creating a link for each file that the folder have ?

Comment: You can loop for that, using a `foreach` loop or something like that.

Comment: So i have put your example on my code and when reload the page, always open the dialog box to download the file. I know it's bad to ask for code, but can you please edit my question with your example to the dialog box only appears if i click on the link of the file ? i'm really strugling with that. Once again thanks for the help

Comment: Use it as `if(IsPost) { .. code here .. }`, or else either try using a variable to detect the condition and only execute that block when the user clicked on the Download button ...

Comment: Have a look at the answer now, I hope it answers your question now :)

Comment: Yes mate. I really apreciated your help. I'm still learning. Sorry to bother you. Thanks a lot !

Comment: So mate just one thing, i've found out that if on IIS -> Headers -> Myme Type then add for example .msg myme type application/octet-stream, it also works.

Comment: Yup! You just need to teach the server to push the file to the client instead of letting the client-agent (browser) handle it :)